# Debugging Rest Controller in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am deploying a spring boot, service broker application for CF. The application defines multiple rest controllers ( for the different service broker endpoints that has to be implemented ).

On testing the application locally and performing a http request using postman, the request is serviced by one of the thread of the runtime ( Please view the attachment ).

My breakpoints dont trigger and i am unable to debug the rest calls. I have changed the debug setting for the breakpoint from suspend Thread to Suspend VM but this does not help either. Please advise how we can debug such calls. I am using eclipse IDE with STS plugin installed.

[image]